Is it possible to use JSONPath with "?()" syntax to filter objects (not array) in Redis?
I'm using node-redis library. I have redis key: test1 with value:
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "requestId": "123",
            "requestType": "TYPE_1",
            "foo": "bar",
            "timestampS": 1230011000
        },
        {
            "requestId": "124",
            "requestType": "TYPE_1",
            "foo": "bar2",
            "timestampS": 1230011050
        }
    ]
}

To get all requests with timestampS < 1230011040, I need to run:
const value = await this.client.json.get('test1', { path: `$.*[?(@.timestampS<1230011040)]` });

It works. The value is an array with one element (request object with "requestId": "123").
However, I don't know how to get an array with all request objects with timestampS < 1230011040 from redis key test2 with value:
{
  "123": {
        "requestId": "123",
        "requestType": "TYPE_1",
        "foo": "bar",
        "timestampS": 1230011000
    },
    "124": {
        "requestId": "124",
        "requestType": "TYPE_1",
        "foo": "bar2",
        "timestampS": 1230011050
    }
}

Is it possible?

It took me a some time, but the solution was easy. I just had to remove the unnecessary star (*) in the JSONPath. This path: $.[?(@.timestampS<1230011040)] works.

In terms of JSON Path, yes, the filter selector operates on both stays and objects.  For objects, it ignores the keys and iterates through the values.
I don't know whether redis supports that, but it's a pretty basic feature, so it should.
Also, when in doubt, just try it.

gregsdennis thank you for your answer. Indeed, as I understand from the documentation: https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/data-types/json/path/, the path: $.*[?(@.timestampS<1230011040)] should work also for objects. However, I tried it and for some reason it doesn't work.

Then I think you're down to consulting any docs they have.  At worst, raise an issue and get support.
